# Запись вектора классов в файл QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, vector, перегрузка-операторов, файловый-ввод-вывод

Требуется записать и считать из файла вектор классов (QT C++)

Родительский класс:

```
class Pentagon :public Figure
{
private:
   double vertex;
   QString name = "pentagon";
   int stack;
public:
   Pentagon(){vertex=5;stack=1;Figure::count++;}
   Pentagon(double vv, int ss){vertex=vv;stack=ss;Figure::count++;}
   ~Pentagon(){stack=0;}
   virtual QString Check(){return name;}
   int CheckSTASH(){return stack;}
   virtual QString Stat(QString n1){return name.append(n1);}
};
```

Дочерний класс:

```
class Star :public Pentagon
{
private:
   double height;
   QString name = "star";
   int stack;
public:
   Star(){height=5;stack=1;}
   Star(double hh,double vv,int ss):Pentagon(vv,ss){height=hh;};
   ~Star(){stack=0;}
   QString Check(){return "star";}
   int CheckSTASH(){return stack;}
   QString Stat(QString n1, QString n2){return name.append(n1).append(n2);}
};
```

Вектор создан такой:

```
    Star vec1; Star vec2; Pentagon vec3;
    QVector <Pentagon> MilkyWay = {vec1,vec2,vec3};
```

Я так понимаю надо переопределять операторы и поэлементно сохранять в последовательности?
Как вообще сохранить приватные переменные?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs#Serialization

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570679/serialization-with-qt